# How to add more than one column with SQLiteDatabase insert method?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I am new to android development and I have a question about the insert method of the SQLiteDatabase class.

For example, if I want to insert one row, which has only one column, I would do the following:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("first_name", "my name");

db.insert("MyTable", null, cv);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use this insert method for two or more columns, for instance, if I wanted to add firstName and lastName. I know how to do that with the classic SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("colname1", "value1");
initialValues.put("colname2", "value2");
...
long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

You can put many pairs into ContentValues.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't knew that.

Comment: then mark the answer, please :-). BTW, I, too, have to check if I read correctly that for map collection adding of a pair key-value is done not by "add", but by "put". The same "put" can merely change the value, if the key is already present in the map.